# Sports Themed Cryptic Clues

Tags: cryptic-clues

The NHL and NBA playoffs have just started, so the latest set of cryptic clues will be sports themed. Some clues may be about sports other than hockey or basketball, and there may be some names.

> The French hear strength for him (6)
>
> Plugs the Light Brigade? (8)
>
> Match coal slice angrily (2,7)
>
> In panic, ingots on the cake (5)
>
> Likelihood of scratcher container (7)

**EDIT:**

I wrote "sports themed clues". As you can see, none of the clues have anything obviously sports-related. It is actually the answers that will be sports-related.

**EDIT 2:**

Clue number three had a spelling error. Fixed now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding 1 & 4 from ChrisCudmore and 5 from gannolloy to get everything in one place.

1 (from Chris Cudmore)

> LeBron (The French - LE Hear Strength -Brawn BRON)

2

> Chargers (plugs=chargers, Charge of the Light Brigade)

3

> El Clasico (typically Real Madrid v Barcelona, anagram of "coal slice")

4 (from Chris Cudmore)

> in pan**ic, ing**ots on the cake - Icing, a penalty in Hockey

5 (from gannolloy)

> Pitcher (P: probability or likelihood, itcher: scratcher)

Comment: This one is right!

Comment: Three is right now as well.

Comment: ARG! Not fair switching languages without a hint!

Comment: Nice one. didn't think of Spanish either

Comment: It can be fixed though.  I'd clue it as: ¿Match coal slice angrily?

Comment: Give him the checkmark.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore I've heard/read several native English speakers use the term.

Comment: @RichardRoe I agree. I don't think you're wrong with how you wrote the clue, I meant I was only thinking of American sports.

Answer (score 3):

1

> LeBron (The French - LE Hear Strength -Brawn BRON

4

> in pan**ic, ing**ots on the cake - Icing, a penalty in Hockey

Comment: these two are right.

Comment: 5, however, is not correct

Comment: wrong answer deleted

Answer (score 3):

5

> Pitcher (P: probability or likelihood, itcher: scratcher)

Possibilities for 3

> Bo Jackson, No Hitters, NY Yankees, 
>  NY Rangers (has anger in it??)

Comment: then it should be CONTAINER, not CONTAINS,

Comment: You think the answer still correct though

Comment: Probably. The clue is inaccurate.

Comment: Correct. It is true that a pitcher "contains" things. I admit it was a bit of a stretch, but I did it to make it more grammatically correct. I will change it though.

Comment: Yeah, these are hard to get exactly right.  If this clue were in my newspaper, I'd right off a nasty letter to the editor beginning with "Sirs, This current generation of puzzle setters.....".   But things are a bit more lenient here.

Comment: I'm taking "Angrily" to be an anagram hint.  So "Coal Slice" should be anagrammed.  But I can't make anything of it.